# Confusion: GitHub Project broken(?), Instructions not clear: Mercurial setup(?)

Tags: github, go

first of all, i've never done something with github, this is my first try, so please be polite and help me on the train.

I would like to use this github-project:
https://github.com/jmmcatee/cracklord which is completly in go language.

from the instructions:
If you'd like to get things build from source, it will first require you to have a working Go build environment with the GOPATH setup. Additionally, you'll probably want Git and Mercurial setup to gather the various libraries and plugins that we've used in the code.

Here are my Questions:
I've done installing git and i'm able to clone the repro, which works fine.
I've installed mercurial, but have no idea how to "setup" mercurial. 
Can someone explain what mercurial setup togehter with this githubproject example means?

why i'm asking
after creating a directory `git-repos`
changing into this directory with `cd git-repos`
path is now `/root/git-repos`

```
# set GOPATH to /root/git-repos
export GOPATH=/root/git-repos
```

and doing `go get github.com/jmmcatee/cracklord`

gives this error-message:

```
go get github.com/jmmcatee/cracklord
can't load package: package github.com/jmmcatee/cracklord: no Go files in /root/git-repos/src/github.com/jmmcatee/cracklord
```

okay. 
So, when i'm following the instructions i'm not able to finish. Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you
Paul

Comment: If you have some trouble with a github repository, ... open an issue in that repository.

Comment: The problem is in cracklord. It's install description is broken at least for Go 1.9.

Comment: Try cloning manually via `git clone` et al. and building manually via `go build`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set gopath anymore, it is set by default to:

```
~/go
```

You don't say which os you're using, but given your paths I assume linux. I suspect you haven't exported the environment variable correctly. You might want to try setting up a simpler package first and verifying you have your go setup right. Follow the instructions here (including verifying your setup is working, and just using the default gopath):

https://golang.org/doc/install

And try downloading and running something simpler (which doesn't require several components installed) to verify your setup first.